# Is there equivalent to PHP's openssl_pkey_get_private in Golang?

Tags: php, go

I have to translate PHP code to Golang and I encoutered this problem.

Comment: Try this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44230634/how-to-read-an-rsa-key-from-file/44231740

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course Go can load x509 private keys, but there is no "do-what-I-want" function, such as openssl_pkey_get_private.

After PEM decoding the key (and possibly decrypting it), use one of the Parse*PrivateKey functions in the [x509 package](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/):

```
package main

import (
    "crypto"
    "crypto/x509"
    "encoding/pem"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    pemBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("sample.key.pem")
    check(err)

    block := firstPrivateKey(pemBytes)
    if block == nil {
        log.Fatal("No private key in input")
    }

    derBytes := block.Bytes
    if x509.IsEncryptedPEMBlock(block) {
        derBytes, err = x509.DecryptPEMBlock(block, []byte("password"))
        check(err)
    }

    var key crypto.PrivateKey
    switch block.Type {
    case "RSA PRIVATE KEY":
        key, err = x509.ParsePKCS1PrivateKey(derBytes) // or PKCS8
        check(err)
    case "EC PRIVATE KEY":
        key, err = x509.ParseECPrivateKey(derBytes)
        check(err)
    default:
        log.Fatal("Unsupported key type")
    }

    fmt.Println(key)
}

func firstPrivateKey(pemBytes []byte) *pem.Block {
    var block *pem.Block
    for len(pemBytes) > 0 {
        block, pemBytes = pem.Decode(pemBytes)
        if strings.HasSuffix(block.Type, " PRIVATE KEY") {
            return block
        }
    }
    return nil
}

func check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```