# How to write *PrivateKey type variable to a file in golang?

Tags: go, cryptography, rsa, private-key, public-key

I have generated a RSA private key (using crypto/rsa) and corresponding public key in go. Now I want to write them to two files (each one to a file), but WriteString and Write functions are specific to string and []byte variable. Also instructions like String(privateKey) generate error. How I can write these keys to the files?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13555085/save-and-load-crypto-rsa-privatekey-to-and-from-the-disk https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64104586/use-golang-to-get-rsa-key-the-same-way-openssl-genrsa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need [`pem.Encode`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/pem#Encode). An example can be seen in [`maplepie/rsa#savePrivateKey()`](https://github.com/maplepie/rsa/blob/5c607500efe74732cd0bb26f3af51509c7725831/pem.go#L46-L61):

```golang
func (p *PemKey) savePrivateKey(privateKey *rsa.PrivateKey, filename string) error {
    raw := x509.MarshalPKCS1PrivateKey(privateKey)
    block := &pem.Block{
        Type:  "RSA PRIVATE KEY",
        Bytes: raw,
    }
    file, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = pem.Encode(file, block)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

Same idea for public key:

```golang
func (p *PemKey) savePublicKey(publicKey *rsa.PublicKey, filename string) error {
    raw, err := x509.MarshalPKIXPublicKey(publicKey)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    block := &pem.Block{
        Type:  "PUBLIC KEY",
        Bytes: raw,
    }
    file, err := os.Create(filename)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    err = pem.Encode(file, block)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```